# Vue.js v-slot in single file component

Tags: vue.js

I have two components: popup and page. Popup is inside page and I want to use named `v-slot`.

Inside popup.vue (single file component), the code is:

```
<template>
  <div>
    ...
    <slot/> // default
    ...
    <slot name="bottom"/> // name slot
  </div>
</template>
```

And now in my page, I import popup and use it like:

```
<template>
  ...
  <popup v-if="...">
    content of slot by default...
    <template v-slot:bottom>
      content text
    </template>
  </popup>
  ...
</template>
```

But there is an error:

> `<template v-slot>` can only appear at the root level inside the
> receiving the component

I've try to bypass with a component but nothing append. Same with shorthand like:

```
<template #bottom>...</template>
```

Comment: Where in the code are you placing this `<template v-slot>`?

Comment: Inside page.vue component. I want to inject data from page.vue to the slot name bottom inside popup.vu component

Comment: No, I mean you can't have default slot template sitting next to named slots, unless you do `<template v-slot:default>`, have a look at [the docs on named slots](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Named-Slots).

Comment: In the doc it's write: A <slot> outlet without name implicitly has the name “default”. Furthermore, i've just test to write v-slot:default but nothing change. I've the same error

Comment: start writing a very simple example like in the docs.

Comment: @YomS. yes you can, v-slot:default is only to be explicit

Comment: @BriceChaponneau Please consider making a verifiable example for this.

Comment: @Slim Exactly, In the code, the OP seems to have the default content without `v-slot`, yet for some reason the error message complains as if it's using one.

Comment: I'm ok with default but this is only sugar like the older syntax of slot. @Yom S. Done, i write my answer...

Answer (score 5):

Ok thanks everybody but it's an error from my side.
I wrote :

```
<popup>
  <div>
    default content
    <template v-slot:bottom>bottom content</template>
  </div>
</popup>
```

But I need to close div before use the template.

```
<popup>
  <div>default content</div>
  <template v-slot:bottom>bottom content</template>
  <!-- </div> -->
</popup>
```

I had too much code and got lost in it.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to tell from your code, but my guess is that your slot template is nested inside another template - which cannot be compiled.

For example:

```html
<popup>
  Test

  <template #bottom><!-- Works -->
    <template>
      Test
    </template>
  </template>
</popup>
```

```html
<popup>
  Test

  <template>
    <template #bottom><!-- Fails, because the slot is not on the root template element. -->
      Test
    </template>
  </template>
</popup>
```

Comment: It's not the reality because page.vue and popup.vue are two components and for sfc we start with a template. If i only use one slot by default, it's OK but not with name as you said. Is it clear ?

Comment: I'm agree with your exemple